# Can i have 2 conditions in protractor expect function? Also give me expect statement to verify whether the getText() has the expected value?

Tags: protractor

Here i want to combine the below 2 expectations into one.

```
expect(button.getText()).toEqual('Process Successful');
expect(button.getText().indexOf('- code 3001')).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

Also whether the below statement is correct or not. I am trying to verify in the getText() whether expected value is present in the text.

```
expect(button.getText().indexOf('- code 3001')).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

Comment: Wait, these are 2 different buttons checked in this case, right?

Comment: I have an idea that might work, but I cannot promise. @alecxe would know. First, if the text could start with the -, I think you would want .toBeGreaterThan(-1). Here is my idea. Create an array call it bArray, say. Probably use an expectedConditions object EC, too. set bArray[0]=(button1.getText()).toEqual('Process Successful')) . set bArray[1]=button2.getText().indexOf('- code 3001')).toBeGreaterThan(-1). Then do expect(bArray).not.toContain(false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `expect().toContain()` to verify text contained in string.

```
expect(button.getText()).toContain('Process Successful');
expect(button.getText()).toContain('- code 3001');
```

You can also do it in another way,

```
var buttonContainsText =  button.getText().then(function(text){
   return (text.indexOf('Process Successful') > -1) && (text.indexOf('- code 3001') > -1)
})
expect(buttonContainsText).toBeTruthy();
```